# Android: Intent in one activity to initiate another activity

Tags: android, button, android-intent

Sorry that I am very new to the android development and now that I would like to workout that when the user presses a button, it will initiate Actitity2, and similarly when the user press the cancel button in Activity2, it will back to the original activity.

I have referenced to the book about writing app but it seems cannot work, the coding is looks simple and as follows:

```
public class NameIndex extends Activity 
{
       // called when the activity is first created
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
          setContentView(R.layout.name_index);

           public button_cancel_click (View view) { /////// <-- ERROR AT THIS LINE
               Intent intent = new Intent (this, GameIndex.class);
               startActivity(intent);
           }
       } // end method onCreate
}
```

The xml layout as follows:

```
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:paddingBottom="10dp"
      android:paddingTop="10dp"      
      android:layout_span="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="button_cancel_click"            
            android:text="Cancel" />     
    </TableRow>
```

The Eclipse reports the above error line as "**button_cancel_click cannot be resolved to a type**", and that for

view "**Illegal modifier for parameter view; only final is permitted**".

How could this be solved?

Comment: your button_cancel_click is inside onCreate. move it outside, a method cannot be in another one.

Comment: Many thanks!! I got your point and moved it outside and it works! sorry for such simple question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are writing the definition of button_cancel_click function in OnCreate function body correct it like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
.
.
.
}
public button_cancel_click (View view) 
{
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The listener should be added this way:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.name_index);
Button button = (Button ) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                       
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent (this, GameIndex.class);
           startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Disagree, you can call action on click through xml too, `android:onClick` is the property given.